# Table view cells mess up after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewCell, containing a specific of UIImages that I generate from code.

I've got this problem: the images are generated fine when I first load the view. However, if, for example, I scroll down and then I go back up, I find a completely different set of images.

I imagine this is a problem connected to the reusable cells, but I really don't know how to solve it.

```
for collabsImages in secImageUrls[indexPath.row] {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.tag = i
        image.userInteractionEnabled = true
        image.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(10 + i*50 + 7*i), self.view.frame.height/2 - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height - 55, 40, 40)
        image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.width/2
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: collabsImages), placeholderImage: nil, options: [])
        cell1.addSubview(image)
        let didTapOnCollabImage = CollabsGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTapOnCollabImage:", row: indexPath.row)
        image.addGestureRecognizer(didTapOnCollabImage)

        i++
    }
}
```

Here's the code for cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
let cell1 : cellTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! cellTableViewCell


        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        cell1.profileImg.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tappedOnImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedOnImage:")

        cell1.profileImg.tag = indexPath.row
        cell1.profileImg.addGestureRecognizer(tappedOnImage)


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                cell1.profileImg.center = CGPointMake(35, 35)
                cell1.usernameLbl.frame = CGRectMake(cell1.profileImg.frame.maxX + 7, cell1.profileImg.frame.minY, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 20)
                cell1.usernameLbl.text = (self.jsonFeeds[indexPath.row]["author"] as? String)!
                cell1.titleLbl.text = (self.jsonFeeds[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String)
                cell1.titleLbl.frame = CGRectMake(cell1.profileImg.frame.maxX + 7, cell1.usernameLbl.frame.maxY + 7, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20)

                let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(cell1.profileImg.frame.minX, cell1.titleLbl.frame.maxY + 20, self.view.frame.width-30, 90))
                //textLabel.center = CGPointMake(cell1.center.x, textLabel.center.y)
                textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
                textLabel.numberOfLines = 7
                textLabel.text = self.jsonFeeds[indexPath.row]["text"] as? String
                textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 109/255, blue: 127/255, alpha: 0.1)
                cell1.contentsView.addSubview(textLabel)

                let btn = UIButton()
                btn.frame = CGRectMake(cell1.frame.maxX - 150, textLabel.frame.maxY + 30, 130, 24)
                btn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
                btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
                btn.setTitle("MESSAGE", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)
                btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
                btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

                cell1.contentsView.addSubview(btn)






            let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {

                (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in

            }


            cell1.profileImg.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: self.imageUrls[indexPath.row]!), completed: block)

            }

            var i = 0
            for collabsImages in secImageUrls[indexPath.row] {

                if collabsImages != "This is a post"{



                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                        let image = UIImageView()
                        image.tag = i
                        image.userInteractionEnabled = true
                        image.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(10 + i*50 + 7*i), self.view.frame.height/2 - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height - 55, 40, 40)
                        image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.width/2
                        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
                        image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: collabsImages), placeholderImage: nil, options: [])
                        cell1.contentsView.addSubview(image)
                        let didTapOnCollabImage = CollabsGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTapOnCollabImage:", row: indexPath.row)
                        image.addGestureRecognizer(didTapOnCollabImage)

                        i++
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return cell1
```

Comment: `cell1.addSubview(image)`, replace this with `cell.contentView.addSubview(image)`. Secondly provide a tag or something in order to remove the imageView from cell when cells are reused in order to manage memory

Comment: I do I actually remove the imageViews from the cell when they are reused?

(I switched to `cell.contentView.addSubview(image)` but nothing has changed) @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: post your cellForRowAtIndexPath. This kind of problem usually has to do with the way you are dequeueing/reusing your cells.

Comment: Added to the post! @Siriss

Comment: Does tapping on the button, and tapping on the image do different things?

Comment: Yes completely different.. @Siriss

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are dispatching to the main thread twice, and once in an existing dispatch call. You should not need to dispatch anything to the main thread in cellForRowAtIndexPath, unless you are doing background work you need to return, like a network fetch.

Second, you should set your image on the reusable cell to nil before the cell is loaded. `image.image = nil` right after you dequeue the cell. That might help make sure you are not reusing the image.

Apple and others have some very great tutorials on how to efficiently load images into a table view, also.

Comment: That's right, but actually my images are all created dynamically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so how can I remove their content as soon as I dequeue de cell?

Answer (score 0):

Using tag along with reusable cells is a bad idea. Try to code the same without the help of tag. Giving indexpath.row as tag value cause weired issues. I think this will help